# Meaning of ハグレ (kanji unknown)

Tags: meaning

The following sentence is from a book. The context is the main characters just finished fighting some monsters. One character looks distracted, and when one of the others asks her if there's something wrong, she says:

> いえね、さっきの化け物が単独。もしくは、ハグレなら問題はないのだけれど。

Since there is no kanji with ハグレ, I'm having problems trying to figure out what they're talking about. Does anyone have an idea based on context? I guessed maybe the word 逸れる, but I'm not sure it makes sense here. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that ハグレ is from the verb はぐれる and means "lone wanderer", "stray one", etc.

はぐれ as a noun is definitely rare and is almost never used in daily conversations.  But J-RPG fans are somewhat familiar with this word because [はぐれメタル](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%90%E3%82%8C%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB) ([Liquid Metal Slime](http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/Liquid_metal_slime) in English) is one of the most popular monsters in the *Dragon Quest* franchise. Actually I feel her use of ハグレ is a reference to this monster.

Aside from this, the only word I know which contains はぐれ is the title of [this TV drama](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%90%E3%82%8C%E5%88%91%E4%BA%8B%E7%B4%94%E6%83%85%E6%B4%BE).

Comment: It's a bit unclear from this answer whether only はぐれ as a noun is rare or the verb はぐれる too.

Comment: @macraf You're right. I edited the answer.

Comment: I'd like to mention that the old English translations also call the monster Metal Babble or Metabble (generally in the games where the bubble slime バブルスライム is called Babble).

Comment: Summon Night games use it as はぐれ召喚獣, so it seems はぐれ is simply the quality of being a stray monster (as opposed to having an owner or boss). But I will not pretend to know anything about Japanese.

Comment: I've been under the impression that はぐれ usually suggests whoever is nonconformist and maverick. Also I remember that はぐれ銃鍛冶 in Cave Story is translated as "Hermit Gunsmith".

Answer (score 0):

Possibly would be from the はぐれる(strayed-verb) made into a noun (stray - noun).  Like 群れから逸れる strayed from the pack.

So your sentence would be "yes, well, if that monster was just by itself.  Or, if it was a stray, there wouldn't be any problem, but..."